# Error al agregar columnas a tabla MySql

Tags: mysql

Que podría estar mal aquí? 
agregando tablas en MySQL (Consulta simple)

```
ALTER TABLE `shaiyar1_almacen`.`sr_productos` ADD
`item_ali` varchar(255),
`item_cat` int(11),
`item_pack` int(11);
```

Este es el error que me devuelve:

`[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'item_cat int(11), item_pack int(11)' at line` 3

Comment: Que error te devuelve?

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`item_cat` int(11),
`item_pack` int(11)' at line 3

Comment: Y si pruebas así ALTER TABLE `shaiyar1_almacen`.`sr_productos` ADD COLUMN
`item_ali` varchar(255), ADD COLUMN
`item_cat` int(11),
ADD COLUMN `item_pack` int(11);

Comment: Si, como imagino, intentas agregar columnas a la tabla, prueba a agregar la palabra `COLUMN` después de `ADD`  y puedes usar `AFTER` si quieres que te las agregue después de una determinada columna ya existente. [Ver este tutorial para más detalles](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-add-column/).

Comment: por que no se coloco de respuesta? si gracias si me funciono

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu consulta completa debe incluir la palabra `COLUMN` lo haces por cada una de las que deseas agregar:

```
ALTER TABLE shaiyar1_almacen.sr_productos 
    ADD COLUMN item_ali varchar(255), 
    ADD COLUMN item_cat int(11), 
    ADD COLUMN item_pack int(11);
```

Si por el contrario quieres eliminar una entonces usarás la palabra `DROP` .

Answer (score 1):

Como lo puedes ver en la documentación de `ALTER TABLE`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html

> #### 13.1.9 ALTER TABLE Syntax
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE tbl_name
>    [alter_specification [, alter_specification] ...]
>    [partition_options]
>
> alter_specification:
>    table_options
>  | ADD [COLUMN] col_name column_definition
>        [FIRST | AFTER col_name]
> ```

Entonces tu consulta tendría que ser.

```
ALTER TABLE `shaiyar1_almacen`.`sr_productos` -- tbl_name
ADD COLUMN `item_ali` varchar(255), -- alter_specification
ADD COLUMN `item_cat` int(11), -- alter_specification
ADD COLUMN `item_pack` int(11) -- alter_specification
```